# CakePHP 3.x - Edit: Dates having empty fields upon submission despite them already existing

Tags: javascript, mysql, cakephp, save, daterangepicker

I have three tables:

- Bookings (where the Form is)
- Sessions (where attributes `date_start` and `date_end` are)

In Sessions table, I have a field for dates that utilises the Daterangepicker jQuery script.

```
<input class='form-control' type="text" name="daterange" id="daterange"
                                   placeholder='Session dates'/>
```

In MySQL, I have two attributes in my Sessions table called `date_start` and `date_end`. When someone uses the 'daterange' input, they are able to use a calendar built from Daterangepicker to select two dates. Upon choosing those two dates, those two dates become `date_start` and `date_end`, and when choosing new dates, those dates are saved successfully.

However, this particular form is the Edit view, not Add, and my problem is that if I don't change the `daterange` form input and then submit the form, it fails to successfully save whatsoever and says attributes date_start and date_end are empty, and need to be filled in (they're not nulls in MySQL). I utilise a Javascript script that inputs the existing date range into the field as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var daterange = '<?= h($booking->session->date_start->i18nFormat('dd/MM/YYYY') . ' - ' . $booking->session->date_end->i18nFormat('dd/MM/YYYY'));?>';
    $('#daterange').val(daterange);
});
</script>
```

If for example, `date_start = 2017-02-02` and `date_end = 2017-02-03`, then the `daterange` form input would then display after converting to my local date format:

> 02/02/2017 - 03/02/2017

$booking refers to this statement from the Controller which was set to the View:

```
$booking = $this->Bookings->get($id,[
    'contain'=>['Sessions']
]);
```

When I do a print of `$booking->session['date_start']` or `$booking->session['date_end']`, I can see the date. In the CakePHP variables, I can also see the dates properly. It's only when submitting, and seeing the request data that they're empty, with the debug of patchEntity also showing as much.

For example, if say prior to using the edit form, date_start = 2017-02-02 and date_end = 2017-02-03, and then do a `pr($booking->session['date_start'])`, I would get a print of 2/2/2017 (local date format).

Also, these are the hidden `date_start` and `date_end` inputs which are automatically filled if the `daterange` input is filled.

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->hidden('session[date_start][year]', ['id' => 'start_year']);
echo $this->Form->hidden('session[date_start][month]', ['id' => 'start_month']);
echo $this->Form->hidden('session[date_start][day]', ['id' => 'start_day']);
echo $this->Form->hidden('session[date_end][year]', ['id' => 'end_year']);
echo $this->Form->hidden('session[date_end][month]', ['id' => 'end_month']);
echo $this->Form->hidden('session[date_end][day]', ['id' => 'end_day']);
?>
```

And the corresponding Daterangepicker JS that does this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear'
        },
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
        startDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        endDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        minDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    });

    $('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
        $("#start_year").val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY'));
        $("#start_month").val(picker.startDate.format('MM'));
        $("#start_day").val(picker.startDate.format('DD'));
        $("#end_year").val(picker.endDate.format('YYYY'));
        $("#end_month").val(picker.endDate.format('MM'));
        $("#end_day").val(picker.endDate.format('DD'));
    });

    $('input[name="daterange"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker){
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
</script>
```

**Summary:** Unless I actively change the dates using the respective form input, the existing dates are emptied for some reason, and the submission fails to save any of the form.

**Update:** I tried two things so far: Doing an unset of `date_start` and `date_end` if empty in the controller as per ahoffner's suggestion, which did not work. I also tried removing the hidden form inputs. This allowed me to submit if the date was not changed, but if I did change them, while the form would still submit successfully, the dates would not change.

**Update 2:** As per ahoffner's request, below is the $this->request->data(). In this particular submit, I changed `amount` to 300, and did not touch the dates. The result failed to save.

```
Array
(
    [session] => Array
        (
            [studio_id] => 2
            [date_start] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 
                    [month] => 
                    [day] => 
                )

            [date_end] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 
                    [month] => 
                    [day] => 
                )

            [session_genre] => test
            [engineer_id] => 2
            [no_people] => 3
            [studio_usage] => test
            [otherpeople_req] => 
            [special_req] => 
            [status] => confirmed
        )

    [optionsRadios] => manydays
    [singledate] => 
    [daterange] => 09/02/2017 - 10/02/2017
    [firstname] => 
    [lastname] => 
    [email] => 
    [phoneno] => 
    [textbox] => 
    [amount] => 300
)
```

The Booking table's initialize function is as follows:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('bookings');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Artists', [
            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('Payments', [
            'foreignKey' => 'booking_id'
        ]);
        $this->hasOne('Sessions', [
            'foreignKey' => 'booking_id'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: What DateRangePicker JS library are you using ? can you give us the link to this library ?

Comment: http://daterangepicker.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's only when submitting, and seeing the request data that they're empty..

When you pass an array in place of an entity value to patchEntity, odd/special things can happen.

As shown in your output of `$this->request->data()`, there *is* a value set for `date_start` & end, an array containing:

```
Array
(
    [year] =>
    [month] =>
    [day] =>
)
```

When a call is made to `patchEntity`, it will attempt to set `$booking->session->date_start` and `date_end` to that array (`['year' => '', 'month' => '', 'day' => '']`).

CakePHP will update the Entity values for **each array key provided** when calling patchEntity or newEntity. Even if the values are blank, or in this case, contain a non-empty array - it will still attempt to update the value of that key.

Since the type on that field is probably a `date` - it will eventually attempt to typecast it to a date-formatted string when marshalling the value. If those keys are all blank, [looking at the source,](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/source-class-Cake.Database.Type.DateTimeType.html#174-176) it basically just drops that array, converting it to `null`. If there are values for those keys, it'll cast them to a date string (like "2017-02-02").

Again, one way to fix this is to make sure not to pass arrays with empty keys to patchEntity, with that format of request data it'd look more like:

```
$data = $this->request->data();

if(empty($data['session']['date_start']['year']) || empty($data['session']['date_start']['month']) || empty($data['session']['date_start']['day'])) {
    unset($data['session']['date_start']);
}

if(empty($data['session']['date_end']['year']) || empty($data['session']['date_end']['month']) || empty($data['session']['date_end']['day'])) {
    unset($data['session']['date_end']);
}

$booking = $this->Bookings->patchEntity($booking, $data);
```

There may be a reason that those are blank on submit however - when they shouldn't be in the first place.  Fixing that would also fix this problem as they wouldn't end up making this blank array. Check the values of those fields (`$("#start_year").val()` etc.), based on the sample code those shouldn't be blank. Is the `'apply.daterangepicker'` function called as expected? And is the values applied (`picker.startDate.format('YYYY')` etc.) as expected?

Comment: So I tried this suggestion, and unset them both before the if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) and after it. Both times, date_start and date_end still appeared to be empty.

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot further without more info. Can you post the code for that entire submit function? The contents of $this->request->data(), and the entity relationships (in the Bookings table's initalize function) could also be helpful

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I've added in $this->request->data() printout, as well as the Booking table's initialize function. For the submit function, it's rather large, with lots of JS and jQuery scripts. If I added it in the post, is just the form and form inputs without the JS & jQuery, bar the DateRangePicker one which is already up there, sufficient?

Comment: Oh I meant the PHP function being submitted too -- but looking at the output of ` $this->request->data()`, when you send an array back for `date_start` and `date_end`, this will have an odd effect in CakePHP. When it calls `patchEntity` (presuming that's how you are saving this), it will effectively unset the value for both. I'll update my answer to illustrate this in a moment.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thank you for your explanation on this.